# Not able to get payload on click on push notification react native

Tags: android, iphone, react-native, push-notification

I am new to react native and some how I have implemented Push Notifications for android and ios. payload is received when notification is received on the phone and sits in notification tray

But when I click the notification application is launching MainActivity of android but I tried to but get same payload on application load in react native and failed to receive that

I have looked for the documents on the web and found that some of the people are working with deeplinking concept for the same.

I have tried few things and failed any overview is thankful.

Comment: which module are u using on react native for push notitications?

Comment: Seems that the problem still continues https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/333